# How to validate DOB from dropdown in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm creating a html form and the form should be validated using Javascript.
While registering, the age of user should be greater than 16 years and I'm taking DOB from dropdown.
Now, my question is how to validate DOB using javscript and user's age shouldn't be greater than 16

I've validated the DOB as you can see in the code but that is not proper way of validation

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var remail = document.getElementById("remail").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


            var status = false;    
            var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


            var x = document.getElementById("male").checked;
            var y = document.getElementById("female").checked;

            var year1 = document.getElementById("year").value;
            var month1 = document.getElementById("month").value;
            var day1 = document.getElementById("day").value;



            if(fname=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter First Name");
            }

            else if(lname=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Last Name");
            }
            else if(email=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Email");
            }
            else if (document.myform.email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1)
             {  
                      alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            }
            else if(remail=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Re-enter Email");
            }

            else if(email != remail)
            {
                alert("Please Check Email");
            }
            else if(password=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Password");
            }
            else if (password.length<8) {
                alert("Please enter 8 digit password");
            }
            else if(day1==0)
            {
                alert("Please select Day")
            }
            else if(month1==0)
            {
                alert("Please select Month")
            }
            else if(year1==0)
            {
                alert("Please select year")
            }
            else if(year1>2003)
            {
                alert("You are not eligible. Age should be above 16...!!!")
            }

            else if(x!=true && y!=true)
            {
                alert("gender");
            }
            else
            {

            alert("Name = " + fname + "\n" + "Last Name = " + lname
                    + "\n" + "Email = " + email
                    + "\n" + "Password = " + password
                    + "\n" + "DOB = " + day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1
                );
            }

        }

    </script>
</head>

<body> 

    <form name="myform">
    <h1>User Registration Form</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Re-enter Email" id="remail"><br><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password"><br><br>

    Birthdate : <br> 
    <select id="day">
        <option value="0">day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    ......

        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>


    <select id="month">
        <option value="0">Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>......          
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>


    <select id="year">
        <option value="0">Year</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>......
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
    </select>
```

Male
   Female

SignUp

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

> NOTE : Try to use a date picker for date selection

```js
function validateDOB(){
  if(document.getElementById('dob').value==''){
    alert('Please select a date')
    return false
  }
  var dob=document.getElementById('dob').value
  console.log(dob)
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dob);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
   if(age<16){
      alert('You are not eligible. Age should be above 16...!!!')
   }
}
```

```html
<input type='date' id='dob'>
<button onclick='validateDOB()'>validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your codes have checked whether the user has selected year, month and date of birth, so you just call my function after your checking is ok.

```
function isValidDate(year, month, date) {
 var dob = new Date(year, month-1, date);

 if (dob.getDate() != date)
   alert("Invalid date value");
 else if ((dob.getMonth() - month) != -1)
         alert("Invalid month value");
      else if (dob.getFullYear() != year)
         alert("Invalid year value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code

```
    function myFunction() {
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var remail = document.getElementById("remail").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


        var status = false;    
        var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


        var x = document.getElementById("male").checked;
        var y = document.getElementById("female").checked;

        var birthday = document.getElementById("bday").value;



        if(fname=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter First Name");
        }

        else if(lname=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Last Name");
        }
        else if(email=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Email");
        }
        else if (document.myform.email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1)
         {  
                  alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        }
        else if(remail=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Re-enter Email");
        }

        else if(email != remail)
        {
            alert("Please Check Email");
        }
        else if(password=="")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Password");
        }
        else if (password.length<8) {
            alert("Please enter 8 digit password");
        }
        else if(!birthday)           //To validate if birth date is empty
        {
            alert("Please select Birth Date")
        }
       else if(submitBday('bday')>16)//To check age greater than 16
        {
           alert("Age should be greater than 16");

        }


        else if(x!=true && y!=true)
        {
            alert("gender");
        }
        else
        {

        alert("Name = " + fname + "\n" + "Last Name = " + lname
                + "\n" + "Email = " + email
                + "\n" + "Password = " + password
                + "\n" + "DOB = " + day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1
            );
        }

    }

   function submitBday(id) {

    var Bdate = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
    var Q4A = ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
    return Q4A;
    }
```

your html code

```
 <form name="myform">
    <h1>User Registration Form</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Re-enter Email" id="remail"><br><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password"><br><br>
    Birthdate :  <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday"">
```

reference http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/exVh2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function validateDOB(){
  if($('#dob').val()==''){
    alert('select dob')
    return false
  }
 var dob=$('#dob').val().replace('-', '')
 var age= moment().diff(moment(dob, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'years');
 
 if(age<16){
  console.log(age)
 alert('You are not eligible. Age should be above 16...!!!')
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type='date' id='dob'>
<button onclick='validateDOB()'>validate</button>
```

Comment: The above prob is a js validation .anyways that was a good effort

Comment: This is a slick solution that works well, but could you please describe _how_ this works? I see there are a couple libraries included that the OP hadn't used in their example

Comment: it uses moment.js and jquery.min.js lib

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, just trying to encourage @mariya sunny to write a well formed answer that can help the community. We are building a knowledge base together

Comment: @tshimkus  , Deepak. Thank you for your support i will try to improve my answer