# Three dropdown date picker with a today button/choice and be able to set a not before or after alert trigger or restriction

Tags: javascript, date, validation, dropdown, picker

I am looking to create a date picker with three separate, movable dropdowns, or other method, for MM DD YYYY.  I would like them to be tied together with a way to choose todays date or even set that as default.  finally I would like to be able to set a not before or not after restriction.  For example there will be three of these on my page, date of birth(DOB), todays date and an expiration date, so the DOB can't be today or after, the expiration date cant be today or before etc.  I am 2 months into teaching myself HTML/CSS/JS, I've figured some stuff out but heavy JS is still very slippery to me.

## So far I have the dropdowns, easy.

```
<div class="select-date">
                    <select id="select-month"">
                    <option value="">MONTH</option>
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="select-day" >
                    <option value="">DAY</option>
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="select-year">
                    <option value="">YEAR</option>
                    <option value="1940">1940</option>
                    <option value="1941">1941</option>
                    <option value="1942">1942</option>
                    <option value="1943">1943</option>
                    <option value="1944">1944</option>
                    <option value="1945">1945</option>
                    <option value="1946">1946</option>
                    <option value="1947">1947</option>
                    <option value="1948">1948</option>
                    <option value="1949">1949</option>
                    <option value="1950">1950</option>
                    <option value="1951">1951</option>
                    <option value="1952">1952</option>
                    <option value="1953">1953</option>
                    <option value="1954">1954</option>
                    <option value="1955">1955</option>
                    <option value="1956">1956</option>
                    <option value="1957">1957</option>
                    <option value="1958">1958</option>
                    <option value="1959">1959</option>
                    <option value="1960">1960</option>
                    <option value="1961">1961</option>
                    <option value="1962">1962</option>
                    <option value="1963">1963</option>
                    <option value="1964">1964</option>
                    <option value="1965">1965</option>
                    <option value="1966">1966</option>
                    <option value="1967">1967</option>
                    <option value="1968">1968</option>
                    <option value="1969">1969</option>
                    <option value="1970">1970</option>
                    <option value="1971">1971</option>
                    <option value="1972">1972</option>
                    <option value="1973">1973</option>
                    <option value="1974">1974</option>
                    <option value="1975">1975</option>
                    <option value="1976">1976</option>
                    <option value="1977">1977</option>
                    <option value="1978">1978</option>
                    <option value="1979">1979</option>
                    <option value="1980">1980</option>
                    <option value="1981">1981</option>
                    <option value="1982">1982</option>
                    <option value="1983">1983</option>
                    <option value="1984">1984</option>
                    <option value="1985">1985</option>
                    <option value="1986">1986</option>
                    <option value="1987">1987</option>
                    <option value="1988">1988</option>
                    <option value="1989">1989</option>
                    <option value="1990">1990</option>
                    <option value="1991">1991</option>
                    <option value="1992">1992</option>
                    <option value="1993">1993</option>
                    <option value="1994">1994</option>
                    <option value="1995">1995</option>
                    <option value="1996">1996</option>
                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                    <option value="1999">1999</option>
                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="2023">2023</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

Update:
After trying a bunch of attempts with bits and pieces from here and there, much progress was made.

```js
function changeContent(){
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById('year').options[0].text = d.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById('month').options[0].text = (d.getMonth() + 1);
        document.getElementById('days').options[0].text = d.getDate();
   }
   
function validateDOB1(){

                      var year=document.getElementById('year').value
  console.log(year)
                var day=document.getElementById('days').value
  console.log(day)
                var month=document.getElementById('month').value
  console.log(month)
                var dob= new Date(year, month -1, day);
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = dob;
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
   if(age<21){
      alert('You are not eligible. Age should be above 21...!!!')
   }
}
```

```css
#days, #month, #year {
    background:none;
    border: solid;
    font-size: 14pt;
    line-height: 15pt;
}
#day {
    width: 50px;
}
#month {
    width: 55px;
}

#year {
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resource/style2.css">
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
               changeContent();
            }
            
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>



    <select id="month" name="month">
        <option value="">MM</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="o4">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">08</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="days" name="days">
        <option value="">DD</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>   
    <select id="year" name="year"onchange ="validateDOB1()">
<option value="2023">2023</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option> 
            <option value="2021">2021</option> 
            <option value="2020">2020</option> 
            <option value="2019">2019</option> 
            <option value="2018">2018</option> 
            <option value="2017">2017</option> 
            <option value="2016">2016</option> 
            <option value="2015">2015</option> 
            <option value="2014">2014</option> 
            <option value="2013">2013</option> 
            <option value="2012">2012</option> 
            <option value="2011">2011</option> 
            <option value="2010">2010</option> 
            <option value="2009">2009</option> 
            <option value="2008">2008</option> 
            <option value="2007">2007</option> 
            <option value="2006">2006</option> 
            <option value="2005">2005</option> 
            <option value="2004">2004</option> 
            <option value="2003">2003</option> 
            <option value="2002">2002</option> 
            <option value="2001">2001</option> 
            <option value="2000">2000</option> 
            <option value="1999">1999</option> 
            <option value="1998">1998</option> 
            <option value="1997">1997</option> 
            <option value="1996">1996</option> 
            <option value="1995">1995</option> 
            <option value="1994">1994</option> 
            <option value="1993">1993</option> 
            <option value="1992">1992</option> 
            <option value="1991">1991</option> 
            <option value="1990">1990</option> 
            <option value="1989">1989</option> 
            <option value="1988">1988</option> 
            <option value="1987">1987</option> 
            <option value="1986">1986</option> 
            <option value="1985">1985</option> 
            <option value="1984">1984</option> 
            <option value="1983">1983</option> 
            <option value="1982">1982</option> 
            <option value="1981">1981</option> 
            <option value="1980">1980</option> 
            <option value="1979">1979</option> 
            <option value="1978">1978</option> 
            <option value="1977">1977</option> 
            <option value="1976">1976</option> 
            <option value="1975">1975</option> 
            <option value="1974">1974</option> 
            <option value="1973">1973</option> 
            <option value="1972">1972</option> 
            <option value="1971">1971</option> 
            <option value="1970">1970</option> 
            <option value="1969">1969</option> 
            <option value="1968">1968</option> 
            <option value="1967">1967</option> 

    </select>>


</body>
</html>
```

The text of the default selects are changed to reflect the broken down date.  So for today's date, it doesn't have to be touched, but if for some reason you need to you can.  Now I have to set up several validations for user chosen dates.  I don't know how to do that yet.

26 June, Many much more progresses!  I think I got this licked.  The updated snippet shows a 3 dropdown date picker that defaults to today(still need to make that two digit), and it checks for age of 21.  Or any amount of years you want.  Can't believe I figured it out.  Credit to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55390011/22058281

and this one: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2011/11/18/validate-date-dropdown-lists-with-javascript-jquery

No JQUERY. Proud of that.  The question is now, am I missing something?  Will this fail or go awry?

ps Perhaps some more help, reading down the javascript for age verification, I understand everything happening until here:

```
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
```

It works, but I can't talk it through to explain what exactly is happening, if that makes sense.  Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Would using html input date with min and max set via JS be an option, rather than having to do all the checking yourself (eg dealing with different month lengths and leap years.).

Comment: That might be useful in a different portion of the website, but here I am locked into the date displaying as MM    DD    YYYY, and the user has to be able to pick.  I can put up guide rails or road blocks(ie not before today) but I can't otherwise determine what they choose.  Hope that clarifies.